# Bind ContextMenu Item inside Button to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, model-view-controller, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a `ContextMenu` with an `ItemMenu` to a button

```
<Button x:Name="RemoteMachine" Command="{Binding ElementName=RemoteMachines, Path=DataContext.RemoteMachineSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                      Command="{Binding ElementName=RemoteMachines, Path=DataContext.DeleteRemoteMachineCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

In my model I have the following

```
public ICommand RemoteMachineSelectedCommand => new CommandHandler(p => MachineSelectedAction(p, true), true);
public ICommand DeleteRemoteMachineCommand => new CommandHandler(p => DeleteRemoteMachineAction(p), true);
```

The Button command works correctly while the ContextMenu one doesn't.
I suppose I'm binding it someway wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use a [BindingProxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

Comment: Thanks man. I've exactly done that.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `Button` to the command and then bind to it from the `MenuItem` using the `PlacementTarget` property of the parent `ContextMenu`:

```
<Button x:Name="RemoteMachine"
        Tag="{Binding ElementName=RemoteMachines, Path=DataContext.DeleteRemoteMachineCommand}"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=RemoteMachines, Path=DataContext.RemoteMachineSelectedCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.CommandParameter,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```